# println(String s) vs println(Object o)

Tags: java

It seems to me that [`PrintStream.print(Object x)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`PrintStream.println(Object x)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.Object%29) are identical to [`PrintStream.print(String x)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) and [`PrintStream.println(String x)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29).

Is there any obvious reason for having both? Are they different in any way? API-docs-readability? Efficiency?

(With autoboxing, I suspect that even the print-methods taking primitives as arguments are redundant... however these methods predate the autoboxing feature so that's explainable.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They don't *do* the same thing:

`print(Object x)` calls `String.valueOf(x)`, which returns:

```
(obj == null) ? "null" : obj.toString();
```

So we have an additional `toString()` method.

The *result* is the same, because `String.toString()` returns `this`. But for the ease of use of the API, the user should not be forced to understand these details.

Answer (score 2):

```
PrintStream.print(Object x)
```

prints string generated by

```
String.valueOf(Object)
```

But

PrintStream.print(String x)

prints the character sequence, if `null` it will print null

Comment: But valueOf returns "null" for null references.